# redefinition happend in which procedure? compile or link time?

Tags: c++, c, compilation

If I defined a function twice, I'll get a redefinition error message, but
I'm confused that redefinition happened in compile or link time?

and why you can override malloc in libc without a redefinition error?

Comment: redefinition happens during linking stage.

Comment: Yes, you can override malloc(), because the linker will only look in libc if the symbol is not already satisfied by your own code. Generic advice: DO NOT TRY THIS unless you *really* know what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

You get a function redefinition error when you have two function with the same prototype or signature (function signature is made of the function name number of parameters and parameter types, does NOT include the return type).

This is a compile time error if the compiler see two functions with the same signature:

```
int foo(int a);
double foo(int b);
```

Why you can override function calls in libraries? Let's look at how the code is build into an executable:

- the compiler is called for each source file and outputs an object file: any function call which cannot be resolved (i.e. calling a function in a different file) is an external symbol which the linker will have to resolve.
- the linker take all the object files and tries to resolve all the symbols; but it does this on a first come first served manner. For a external symbol it will consider the first definition it finds and not worry about the fact that there may be more definitions of the same symbol available.

So, the linker actually allows you to override a function's behavior. And it all depends on the order the files are linked - the first function definition it finds is the one used to resolve the symbol.

Hope this sheds some light on the matter.

Comment: thank you Pandrei,
does the "first come first served manner" only apply in shared libraries?

here's what I'm trying, main.cpp called a function defined in def1.cpp and def2.cpp:
gcc main.cpp  def1.cpp def2.cpp    // multiple definition error
but
gcc main.cpp def1.so def2.so //  yes, first come first served manner

what is the difference?

Comment: @SamH.W no, it does not apply to libraries; actually the linker does not know the difference; it only takes in a bunch of object files and tries to resolve the symbols.Try this: one header file with the function prototype, two source files, each with it's own implementation and call the function in main(). This should build even though you have two distinct implementations for the same function.

Answer (score 0):

Either or both.   It can also result from the programmer editing source code or modifying build scripts.

"Redefinition" errors are emitted when the linker find two things (symbols) with the same name.

There are many reasons the linker might find two symbols with the same name.   Some possibilities (there are many permutations) include;

- An object file is specified twice in the link command.  This usually results from an error in a build script.
- Two object files that contain the same function definition.  This results from code duplication - for example, a function definition being copied into different source files, which are then compiled and linked.   It can also result from monkey business with the preprocessor (e.g. `#include`ing a file that contains the definition of a global variable by two source files).

The causes of things like the above are generally programmer error (e.g. supplying a bad linker command in a build script, misuse of the preprocessor, copying and pasting code between projects.

The reason functions in libraries like libc can often be "overridden" is that the linker typically only looks for symbols in libraries if it can't find them in object files.  So, if an object file defines `malloc()` the linker will resolve all calls to that, and not attempt to resolve using the version in a library.    This sort of thing is quite dangerous, because some other functions within libraries (e.g. even within libc) may resolve directly to the original `malloc()` (e.g. some calls may be inlined) which can unpredictable behaviours.    This sort of behaviour is also linker specific:  although this sort of thing is common with unix/linux variants, there are systems where the linkers do things differently.